# New version for iOS app in status "Ready for Submit" on manual release in the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

Can an iOS application be updated to a new version after it has been reviewed and has the status Ready for Submit in the AppStore?
The app is set to Manual Release.
Must I remove the current build and upload the new one, or can I just update the same build to a newer version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the current build and need to upload the newer one.

Answer (score 1):

> Must I remove the current build and upload the new one, or can I just update the same build to a newer version?

The former. You can never “just update the same build to a newer version”. Remove your binary and go thru the whole process again. There are no shortcuts.